# How to get two synchronised generators from a function

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, yield

i have a nested tuple like this one :

```
this_one = (w,h,(1,2,4,8,16),(0,2,3,4,6),("0"),("0"),(0,1))
```

It will be used to feed:
`itertools.product(*this_one)`

`w` and `h` have to be both generators.

Generated values from `h` depends on generated values from `w` as in this function:

```
def This_Function(maxvalue):

   for i in range(maxvalue):
       w_must_generate = i
       for j in range(i+1):
           h_must_generate = j
```

Iv tried using a yield in `This_function(maxvalue)`:

```
def This_Function(maxvalue):

   for i in range(maxvalue):
       for j in range(i+1):
           yield i,j
```

Returning a single generator object which gives:

```
which_gives = itertools.product(*this_one)
for result in which_gives:
    print(result)
...
((23,22),(16),(6),(0),(0),(0))
((23,22),(16),(6),(0),(0),(1))
((23,23),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0))
...
```

A single tuple at `result[0]` holding 2 values.

And this is not what i want .

The result i want has to be like the following:

```
the_following = itertools.product(*this_one)
for result in the_following:
    print(result)
...
((23),(22),(16),(6),(0),(0),(0))
((23),(22),(16),(6),(0),(0),(1))
((23),(23),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0))
...
```

**Without** having to do something like :

```
the_following = itertools.product(*this_one)
for result in the_following:
    something_like = tuple(result[0][0],result[0][1],result[1],...,result[5])
    print(something_like)
...
((23),(22),(16),(6),(0),(0),(0))
((23),(22),(16),(6),(0),(0),(1))
((23),(23),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0))
...
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: `something_like = result[0] + result[1:]` doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: @TimRoberts not when your dealing with `maxvalue = 2147483647`

Comment: Why does that matter in the slightest?

Comment: @TimRoberts for each tuple in the final result ot this post i need to manipulate a lot of datas to create an image then try if it opens without warning or error and behave accordingly ..it takes time .

Comment: Maybe so, but why does that matter here?  Your "without having to do something like" section solves the problem you have described, and my adjustment merely makes that code prettier to read.  I don't care how long it takes to process each tuple.

Comment: @TimRoberts You are right my bad , Thnks you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fundamentally not how `product` works. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Before product() runs, it completely consumes the input iterables, keeping pools of values in memory to generate the products. Accordingly, it is only useful with finite inputs.

Thus, having the second one be dependent won't get you the result you want, assuming that is for `h` values to always be `w+1..max` in the resulting output sequence.

I'm not sure why you couldn't just run it with your `This_function` approach and destructure it with a generator expression:

```py
result = ((a, b, c, d, e, f, g) 
          for ((a, b), c, d, e, f, g) in itertools.product(*this_one))
```

Comment: Because `this_one` is a specific case from another list of tuples it need to fit with the rest of the tuples format but thnks i didnt know about product() keeping all values in memory!

Comment: So, are you saying your data is not actually as you have described it above?

Comment: @TimRoberts No it is exactly the same except for the other tuple this is why `this_one` must be like the other to gain some time during the loop

Comment: What you are asking cannot be achieved with generators.  `product` will match the FIRST element of `w` with EVERY element of `h`, and then match the SECOND element of `w` with EVERY element of `h`.  You need to use one of the tuple hacks presented here to achieve your goal.

Comment: That is what i was afraid of  , thnks for ur time anyway sir

Answer (score 1):

Since the values are all entirely determined, this works and is fairly legible:

```
from itertools import product

maxvalue = 5
w = (i for i in range(maxvalue) for j in range(i + 1))
h = (j for i in range(maxvalue) for j in range(i + 1))

this_one = (w, h, (1, 2, 4, 8, 16), (0, 2, 3, 4, 6), ("0"), ("0"), (0, 1))

result = product(*this_one)
```

The values yielded from `w` are basically `0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...` and the values yielded from `h` are `0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...`. Plus, the code pretty much looks like your description of the desired behaviour, which is generally a good thing.

Both `w` and `h` are generators, no space is wasted and the solution is fairly optimal. I just can't tell if `result` is what you actually need, but that depends on what you need and expect `product()` to do here.

Comment: Indeed yes but it is also creating a lot of identical tuple already generated from what i v just checked.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by that - it generates exactly the values `product()` needs, exactly when it needs it. Sure, `w` yields the same value a required number of times, but the cost of that is next to nothing - and if you don't want that, I can only refer to @tzaman's answer: that's not how generators and `product()` work. How do you imagine you would tell `itertools.product()` when to get the generator to yield a value, and when not to?

Comment: Perhaps your example `This_Function()` does not in fact generate the values you want `w` and `h` to generate in that order? In that case, I can't help without more information - you should simplify your question and be more specific about the actual problem here. But it sounds like you should probably write a generator that simply yields what you need one at a time using a couple of basic loops, instead of messing around with generators and `itertools.product()` then.

Comment: He's right, your code does generate duplicates.  That's because he needs `w` and `h` to advance in lock step.  Your code ends up matching each `w` with each `h`.  You should  be getting 750 entries, and you get 11,250.  It's the difference between `zip(w,h)` and `product(w,h)`.

Comment: @Grismar no the values from `This_Function()` are fine . i v just hoped there was a way  from that single function to make 2 generator which hold the same value from both loop and behave the same way as the loop itself ..looks like this is not possible ..but i had to ask!

Comment: @TimRoberts - I see what you mean, I merely focussed on creating the generators that matched what was needed according to OP, not what the desired end result is; it does seem like `product()` is not at all what is needed there.